# My react app is crashing even after error handling. Why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a react component that will display movie details after getting details from the TMDb API. The app working perfectly but there is one condition I am trying to handle i.e. when the movie is not found. In that, I case I want my background to be white instead of the movie poster. I want the same thing for title, overview, rating etc. I have used ternary operator for this.

However, my app still crashes this: -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop_path')
    at HeroArea
```

Here is my code: -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import MovieDetailModal from '../MovieDetailsModal/MovieDetailModal';
import './HeroArea.css';

function HeroArea({ movie }) {

    const [displayModal, setDisplayModal] = useState(false);
    const displayMovieModal = () => setDisplayModal(true);
    
    //Default background if movie.backdrop isn't found
    const backdropImage = movie.backdrop_path !== null ? 
                                { backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.backdrop_path})` } 
                            :   {backgroundColor : "white"};
    return (
        <>
            <MovieDetailModal status={displayModal} movie={movie} setStatus={setDisplayModal} />
            <div className="hero-container" style={backdropImage} >
                <div className="content-width info-container">
                    <div className="inner-container">
                        <h1>{movie.title ? movie.title : "No results found!"}</h1>
                        <p>{movie.overview ? movie.overview.substring(0, 250) : ""}...</p>
                        <button
                            onClick={displayMovieModal}
                            className="common-button view-more-button-hero">Display more</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default HeroArea
```

Comment: Where is the error handling you mention?

Comment: Check the variable assignment of backdropImage

Comment: We might need more context here to fix the issue. But, a quick look at the code shows no sign of error handling. 

The above error posted by you shows that the movie prop itself is not defined and you are trying to read a property on an undefined object.

Try this `function HeroArea({ movie = {} }) {`
or you could do 
`const backdropImage = movie && movie.backdrop_path ?                      {backgroundImage:url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.backdrop_path}) } :   {backgroundColor : "white"};`

Comment: just add a question mark where you try to read `backdrop_path`, like this `movie?.backdrop_path`. that tells JavaScript that movie might be `undefined`

Comment: Simply adding default {} to argument worked! Thanks

Comment: @killerprince182 That won't work if `movie` is undefined. You should check it with this: `movie?.backdrop_path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, because movie is undefined, you can't access its properties.

You would need to make sure that `movie` is set before anything else for example:

```
const backdropImage = movie.backdrop_path !== null 
  ? { backgroundImage:`url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.backdrop_path})` } 
  : {backgroundColor : "white"};
```

BECOMES

```
const backdropImage = movie && movie.backdrop_path !== null 
  ? { backgroundImage:`url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.backdrop_path})` } 
  : {backgroundColor : "white"};
```

---

This also means you will need to make sure you only render this component if movie is set. for example:

```
    return (
        <>
            <MovieDetailModal status={displayModal} movie={movie} setStatus={setDisplayModal} />
            <div className="hero-container" style={backdropImage} >
                <div className="content-width info-container">
                    <div className="inner-container">
                        <h1>{movie.title ? movie.title : "No results found!"}</h1>
                        <p>{movie.overview ? movie.overview.substring(0, 250) : ""}...</p>
                        <button
                            onClick={displayMovieModal}
                            className="common-button view-more-button-hero">Display more</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

BECOMES

```
if(movie){
    return (
        <>
            <MovieDetailModal status={displayModal} movie={movie} setStatus={setDisplayModal} />
            <div className="hero-container" style={backdropImage} >
                <div className="content-width info-container">
                    <div className="inner-container">
                        <h1>{movie.title ? movie.title : "No results found!"}</h1>
                        <p>{movie.overview ? movie.overview.substring(0, 250) : ""}...</p>
                        <button
                            onClick={displayMovieModal}
                            className="common-button view-more-button-hero">Display more</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
return null;
```

Comment: These days, you can do `movie?.backdrop_path !== null` instead of `movie && movie.backdrop_path !== null`.